# WooCommerce how to update product category description and thumbnail ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms, woocommerce-theming

I've got an array of data with which I'd like to update my products categories (taxanomy) metadata. Specifically, I'm trying to update `description` as well as `thumbnail url` values. I tried to use multiple wordpress functions but none of them worked! I didn't get any error but those values didn't get updated either.

```php
$row_data = array(
      'Term ID' => 150,
      'Name' => "my 1st category",
      'Slug' => "my-1st-category",
      'Term URI' => "",
      'Parent Term ID' => "",
      'Description' => "My best description on this category that would change your life forever!",
      'Display Type' => "",
      'Image' => "https://myexample.site/wp-content/"
    );

// This did not work!
wp_update_term($row_data['Term ID'], 'product_cat', $row_data);  

// This did not work either!
update_term_meta($row_data['Term ID'], 'description', $row_data['Description']);  

// This did not work either!
update_woocommerce_term_meta($row_data['Term ID'],  'thumbnail_id',  $row_data['Image']);
```

Is there something that i'm missing?

Is `thumbnail_id` the right field name that i'm using here?

Is `update_woocommerce_term_meta` the right function for updating the thumbnail url?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `update_term_meta($row_data['Term ID'], 'description', $row_data['Description']);` working fine for me.

Comment: @Bhautik Thank you for taking a look at this. Is that right? hmmmmmm interesting! Can't get it to work on my end! What about the other one? Do you happen to know anything about the ```thumbnail url``` field?  Can't find its field name in the database either, neither can i find the "right" function for updating that.

Comment: Where you did this code?

Comment: @Bhautik I ran it on a page of my website (in development). i didn't hook it to any action/filter hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  main problem come from your array keys that are wrong to insert or update a term.

From your custom array *(updated)*:

```
$row_data = array(
    'Term ID'        => 150,
    'Name'           => 'my 1st category',
    'Slug'           => 'my-1st-category',
    'Taxonomy'       => 'product_cat'
    'Parent Term ID' => 0,
    'Description'    => __("My best description on this category that would change your life forever!", "woocommerce"),
    'Display Type'   => "",
    'Image ID'       => "356",
);
```

1. To update term description, use [WordPress `wp_update_term()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_term/) as follows:

```
wp_update_term( $row_data['Term ID'], $row_data['Taxonomy'], array('description' => $row_data['Description']) );
```

2. To update the thumbnail ID *(and not an Image URL)*, use [`update_term_meta()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/) as follows:

```
update_term_meta( $row_data['Term ID'], 'thumbnail_id', $row_data['Image ID'] );
```

Both are tested an works.

---

To insert a new term you will use [WordPress `wp_insert_term()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) like:

```
$term_data = wp_insert_term( $row_data['Name'], $row_data['Taxonomy'], array(
    'description' => $row_data['Description'],
    'slug'        => $row_data['Slug'],
    'parent'      => $row_data['Parent Term ID'],
) );

if ( ! empty($row_data['Display Type']) ) {
    update_term_meta( $row_data['Term ID'], 'display_type', $row_data['Display Type'] );

if ( ! empty($row_data['Image ID']) ) {
    update_term_meta( $row_data['Term ID'], 'thumbnail_id', $row_data['Image ID'] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for debugging this, I really appreciate it. For "description" it worked. I'm sure for the "'thumbnail_id'" would work too. But the problem is, I have the actual "url" to the thumbnail, I don't have the "id" of that thumbnail. I guess I have to find a way to find the ```thumbnail id``` using the ```thumbnail url```.